# цикл if, как вывести из массива только нужную группу?

Tags: php

```
   <?php  
   $data = [
  [ 
    'name' => 'Grayson Allen' , 
    'group' => 'administrator', 
    'email' => 'john@gmail.com', 
    'phone' =>'123-675-34'
  ],
  [ 
    'name' => 'Steven Adams' , 
    'group' => 'student', 
    'email' => 'gray23@gmail.com', 
    'phone' =>'123-346-65'
 ],
 [ 
    'name' => 'Kostas Antetokoumpo' , 
    'group' => 'teacher', 
    'email' => 'king-gary@gmail.com', 
    'phone' =>'123-475-56'
 ],
 [ 
    'name' => 'Dwayne Bacon' , 
    'group' => 'administrator', 
    'email' => 'StreetGarden@gmail.com', 
    'phone' =>'123-787-67'
 ],
 ]  
 ?>
   из этого массива хочу показать только админов.
   if($date['group'] == 'administrator')
    <!-- как дальше-->
    <?php foreach ($data as $key => $crew):?>
       <?=$crew['group']?>
     <?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: `foreach ($data as $d) { if ($d['group'] === 'administrator') { echo $d['name']; } }`  элементарные же вещи...

Answer (score 0):

if должно быть внутри цикла.
Вы перебираете все элементы массива с помощью foreach
и внутри цикла к текущему (рассматриваемому) элементу примеряете условие if .

```
<?php 
foreach ( $data as $crew_item ):
   // $crew_item - это одна группа из массива (по вашей терминологии) 
   if ( $crew_item['group'] == 'administrator' ):
      echo 'Администратор:' . PHP_EOL;
      echo 'имя: ' .$crew_item['name'] . PHP_EOL;
      echo 'email: ' .$crew_item['email'] . PHP_EOL;
      echo 'телефон: ' .$crew_item['phone'] . PHP_EOL;
   endif;
endforeach;
?>
```

PS Не рекомендуется использовать краткий вывод <?= Лучше писать <? echo

PPS Как правильно отметили в комментариях, начиная с PHP 5.4.0 <?= является кратким тегом для конструкции <?php echo и работает даже при отключенном short_open_tag. Поэтому нет ограничений на использование <?=

Comment: Это почему же не рекомендуется писать **<?=**?

Comment: Мне тоже интересно, скажите пожалуйста

Comment: Потому что Вы завязаны на короткий тег (опция short_open_tag). Это не ошибка, но будьте готовы к тому что где-то эта опция не включена и всё сломается. Правильным считается <?php 
Тег <? совпадает с XML форматом и это не хорошо.

Comment: Вообще-то `<?=` __не является коротким тегом__. Даже официальное руководство рекомендует его использовать - https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Comment: Признаю, начиная с PHP 5.4.0 <?= является "коротким тегом" <?php echo , но при этом не является коротким тегом <?php и будет работать даже при отключенном short_open_tag